# Issues using python2 to pass git commands to the OS

Tags: python, git, jenkins

below is my python script, note this is for testing.

```py
from types import StringType
from os.path import isabs
from os import system, popen, getenv
from glob import glob
        
cmd = "ssh-add -l"
returned_value = system(cmd)  # returns the exit code in unix
print('returned value:', returned_value)


cmd = "git clone git@bitbucket.org:XXXXXXXXXX/python_git_test.git"
returned_value = system(cmd)  # returns the exit code in unix
print('returned value:', returned_value)
```

When I run this from CMD

```sh
C:\Users\jenkins\Desktop>python test.py
3072 SHA256:dl91g2BDUmEVpRqqBjJ8oXeHsEKYueW+LpmwCcGkd7I jenkins@cibuild1 (RSA)
3072 SHA256:i5kOlssdnL1g4RzB65bOira+4Y7LcSngp4sLCPb8aXI jenkins@CIBUILD3 (RSA)
('returned value:', 0)
Cloning into 'python_git_test'...
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
        
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
('returned value:', 128)
```

When I run this from gitbash

```sh
$ python test.py
3072 SHA256:dl91g2BDUmEVpRqqBjJ8oXeHsEKYueW+LpmwCcGkd7I jenkins@cibuild1 (RSA)
Cloning into 'python_git_test'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 3, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (3/3), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Receiving objects: 100% (3/3), done.
('returned value:', 0)
('returned value:', 0)
```

I have a couple of questions, why when both gitbash and cmd have the correct key loaded in ssh-agent am I getting an error on CMD?

Second, This is a small snippet from a larger Jenkins build issue. So generally speaking jenkins is the one that calls the git updater python file, I consistently get the access denied publickey.  Does anyone know what terminal jenkins would be trying to use?  I'm assuming CMD?

Comment: Use the `subprocess` module for running external commands.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for fixing the formatting.  Thank you for the suggestion Chepner, Subprocess returned the same issue.  gitbash works cmd does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try and set `set "GIT_SSH_COMMAND=ssh -Tv"` first, before `python test.py` in CMD.

You will see exactly what Git is using as SSH key, to understand why it does not access the remote repository.

You can do the same in a `git bash` session (where the environment variable set in the CMD will be inherited).

Comment: VonC,Thank you so very much.  That gave me the debug info I needed to fix the issue.

Comment: @dae Great! What was the actual issue?

Comment: Best that I could tell, when python called git it seemed to completely ignore ssh-agent and any keys loaded.  Ended up making a .ssh/config file with the correct key listed, I had to remove the passphrase to get jenkins to work.